# Typeerror Float not subscriptable

Tags: python

I have a list (g.ordered) and I want to add an element to that list in the correct order. g.ordered is structured:

```
# all values are floats
g.ordered = [
  [[a, b, c, d...], [A]],
  [[e, f, g, h...], [B]]...
]

# Where A is < B is < ...
```

I want to add

```
x = [[q, w, e, r...], [C]]
# Where C can be any float
```

I have written a function that should work:

```
def insert(x):
    for i in range(len(g.ordered)):

        print(g.ordered[i][1])
        print(x[1])

        if(g.ordered[i][1] > x[1]):
           break
        g.ordered = g.ordered[:i] + x + g.ordered[i:]
```

Now the part I dont understand:
when I include the print statements it prints how I want it to:

```
>>> g.ordered[0][1]
A
>>> X[1]
C
```

But after it prints it gives me an error;

```
print(g.ordered[i][1])
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

This is after it has already completed the next line.

Full Error with prints:

```
-4.882695743122578 # this is the A value
 0.01 # this is the C value
# those where the expected prints which are in line 50 and 51 respecively

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jjrreett/Genetic.py", line 57, in <module>
    insert([[1,2,3,4,5], 0.01])
  File "/home/jjrreett/Genetic.py", line 50, in insert
    print(g.ordered[i][1])
```

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: At line 49 
print g.ordered[i] if it's a float the answer is you made a mistake somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `g.ordered` to the result of the computation, when you really meant `g.ordered[i]`:

```
def insert(x):
    for i in range(len(g.ordered)):
        ...
        g.ordered[i] = g.ordered[:i] + x + g.ordered[i:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You incorrectly rebuild the list.

```
g.ordered = g.ordered[:i] + x + g.ordered[i:]
```

must be:

```
g.ordered = g.ordered[:i] + [x] + g.ordered[i:]
```

Also, this statement must be outside of the loop. However, a more robust solution would be to append the new list to the end of `g.ordered` and then re-sort the list by ABC:

```
def insert(x):
    g.ordered.append(x)
    g.ordered = sorted(g.ordered, key=lambda x:x[1][0])
```

Comment: Thank You. You were 100% right.  The problem with reordering the list everytime is that this will be in a loop so I don't want time to be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
def insert(x):    # you later try to subscript this float
    for i in range(len(g.ordered)):

        print(g.ordered[i][1])

        # On the following line, `x` is the float you passed in
        # as a parameter. You can't subscript a float.
        print(x[1])

        # Here again, you subscript the float `x`
        # also, g.ordered[i][1] is a single element list `[A]`
        # and not a value.  g.ordered[i][1][0] would be `A`
        if(g.ordered[i][1] > x[1]):
            break

        # This is not how you insert a value into a list.
        # Should be g.ordered[:i] + [x] + g.ordered[i:]
        # and not   g.ordered[:i] + x + g.ordered[i:]
        # Or, better yet, just use g.ordered.insert(i, x)
        g.ordered = g.ordered[:i] + x + g.ordered[i:]
```

even after fixing all that, your function still won't do what you intend. It inserts a single value (the parameter `x`) into g.ordered rather than a structure of the form `[[q, w, e, r, ...], [C]]`.

Furthermore, the logic you're using to decide where to insert doesn't seem like it will do what you expect.

DYZ's solution looks like it should solve your problem quite elegantly though.

Keep in mind however, that with his solution you need to pass in a structure of the form `[[q, w, e, r, ...], [C]]` and not just a float. Based on the error you mentioned you were getting, it seems like you're passing in a single float value rather than a structure of the correct form. So you'll still need whatever code it takes to build that properly.